# Конфиг nginx для поддомена

Tags: nginx, сервер, администрирование

Нужно сделать так чтобы на `поддомене:8090` открывался определенный каталог, но при этом чтобы порт `8090` не слушался для основного домена и других поддоменов. Например если домен `site.com` то `http://test.site.com:8090/` нужно обрабатывать и открывать определенный каталог, но не обрабатывать `http://site.com:8090/` или `http://www.site.com:8090/`
Мой конфиг nginx

```
    server {
    listen       8090;
    server_name  test.site.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```

Хоть и `server_name` указан `test.site.com;` но если зайти по адресу site.com:8090 то отрабатывает тот же каталог. Как их разграничить?

Comment: Нельзя не обрабатывать запрос. Но можно написать дополнительный серверный блок который будет на все запросы по неправильным доменам отвечать 404.

Comment: В моем случае как бы это могло выглядеть? Можете написать в ответ, а я его помечу как решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто определяем серверный блок который будет обрабатывать все запросы и отвечать на них 404.

```
server {
    listen 8090 default_server;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо в моем случае все ок :)

Comment: Лучше `return 444` наверное — тогда соединение будет вообще закрываться без конкретного ответа

Comment: Ну это по желанию. Хоть 418 =)